# How to group routes in Swagger-UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, swagger, ruby-grape, swagger-ui

I'm using Grape (on Rails 4), Swagger and Swagger-UI to document my Grape API. Now I wonder how to group routes like the Swagger example: http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/

Thats how my Swagger-UI currently looks:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your endpoint within a `resource` block, for example:

```
module MyApiModule
  class MyApiClass < Grape::API

    resource :foo do
      get :time do
        {epoch_time: Time.now.to_i.to_s}
      end
    end

    resource :bar do
      get :bar_time do
        {epoch_bar_time: Time.now.to_i.to_s}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

... you will see this nice separators:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `resource` blocks already. Perhaps this is a feature of a newer version?

Comment: I wrote this example with `grape-swagger (0.6.0)` and `grape-swagger-ui (0.0.1)`

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. Any ideas or more information about that topic?

Comment: I'm using a Grape on Rack implementation and this isn't working for me. Maybe because I'm not using the ```grape-swagger-ui```?

@Slevin Sounds like this didn't solve your problem. I'm not sure why it's marked as solved.

Comment: I've created a test-api with `grape-swagger` and `grape-swagger-ui` and it worked, but I don't know, why it doesn't work without `grapw-swagger-ui`, so this question should be marked as half-solved :)